# Firebase security - let each user to write himself

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following structure of 'neighbors' in firebase:

```
neighbors: {
user100:{
    user200:{
        from:'1.2'
    },
    user300:{
        from:'4.2'
    },
    user400:{
        from:'2.4'
    }
},
user700:{
    user200:{
        from:'8.7'
    },
    user500:{
        from:'10.3'
    }
}

}
```

support user100, user200 are auth-ids.
I want to let each user to write only him-self, but to do it for every other user he want.
For example, I want to let user200 to write that he is neighbor of user500, but I don't want to let him write that other user (like user 800) is neighbor of someone.

I tried hard but didn't success.
By default I tried this following solution but still not work!!!
the solution was to change the structure to look like:

```
neighbors:  {
user100:{
    user200:{
        from:'1.2',
        neighbor:'user200'
    },
    user300:{
        from:'4.2',
        neighbor:'user300'
    },
    user400:{
        from:'2.4',
        neighbor:'user400'
    }
},
user700:{
    user200:{
        from:'8.7',
        neighbor:'user200'
    },
    user500:{
        from:'10.3',
        neighbor:'user500'
    }
}

  }
```

And the rule is:

```
 neighbors:{
    ".write":"newData.child('neighbor').val() == auth.uid
 }
```

But I get permission-denied!

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule checks for an immediate child of the neighbours object.
It seems like you're writing to a child of each child of the neighbours object.

For example, in your example above the path to the first `neighbor` value would look something like `neighbor/user100/user200/neighbor`

The rule would have to be something like.

```
neighbors:{
    $user_id {
        ".write":"newData.child('neighbor').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Or, if you just want to check the parent keys, which seem to be identical to the value of neighbor (?):

```
neighbors:{
    $user_id {
        ".write":"$user_id == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

In these example `$user_id` is a stand in for the key the rule applies to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    "neighbors":{
    "$user_id":{
        ".write":"newData.child('neighbor').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```